# String.valueOf(float) CLDC 1.0

Tags: java, java-me

В конфигурации CLDC 1.0 нет метода по преобразованию float в string. Поэтому пришлось написать самому. Это вообще не вопрос, может просто кому полезным будет. Юниттесты не делал, но в  моем приложение работает без багов.

- первый параметр - число [3233 милливольт]
- второй сколько раз поделить на 10 [3]
- третий параметр - точность [1]

В результате получим строку "3.2" или с параметрами -54 1 3 будет -5.400.

```
public static String GetFloat(int val, int div, int pres){
    StringBuffer sb=new StringBuffer();       
    char[] schars;
    if (val>=0){
        schars=String.valueOf(val).toCharArray();
    }else{
        sb.append("-");
        schars=String.valueOf(-val).toCharArray();
    }

    if (schars.length<=div){ 
        int i;
        int div_cnt=div-schars.length+1;
        sb.append("0.");
        for (i=1;i<div_cnt;i++){
           sb.append("0");
        }
        int zeros=i-1;
        if (zeros<pres){
            i=0;
            while(zeros+i<pres){                   
                if (i>=schars.length){
                    sb.append("0");i++;
                }else{
                    sb.append(schars[i++]);
                }
            }
        }
    }else{
        int prs=0;
        int i=0;//schars ptr
        int pointAfter=schars.length-div;
        while(i<pointAfter){                
            if (i<schars.length)
                sb.append(schars[i++]);
        }
        sb.append(".");
        while(prs<pres)
        {
            if (i<schars.length){
                sb.append(schars[i++]);
            }else{
                sb.append("0");
            }
            prs++;
        }
    }

    return sb.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

А чем вам не понравился BigDecimal?

```
new BigDecimal(5.243454).setScale(2,BigDecimal.ROUND_FLOOR).toPlainString()
```

Выведет на экран "5.24"